# Xamarin.Forms - Labels Binding

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms

While being so close to finishing my project, I have one issue... While trying to bind results to my labels, I keep getting these errors:

```
Binding: 'Publisher' property not found on 'Nintendo', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
Binding: 'Publisher' property not found on 'Nintendo', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
Binding: 'Platform' property not found on 'Wii U', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
Binding: 'Platform' property not found on 'Wii U', target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'
```

I've looked at multiple sites for help but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working properly. The results (Nintendo, Wii U) are correct and are showing in these errors but nothing is being binded to my labels. So my question is... What exactly am I doing wrong?

Here's my xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       x:Class="Finale.DetailsPage"
                       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Finale;assembly=Finale"
             Title="{Binding Name}"
             BackgroundColor="White">
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Padding="5, 25">
      <Label x:Name="lblTitle"
      Text="{Binding Name}"
                 Font="Bold,Large"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      <Image x:Name="imgCover"
      Source="{Binding Image}"  
                 WidthRequest="200" 
                 HeightRequest="200"/>

      <StackLayout Padding="50, 10">

            <!-- Developer -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="Developer(s):"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
              <Label x:Name="lblDeveloper"
              Text="{Binding Developer}"
                     Font="Bold,Medium" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Publisher -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="Publisher(s):"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
              <Label x:Name="lblPublisher"
              Text="{Binding Publisher}"
                     Font="Bold,Medium" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Platform -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="Platform(s):"
                      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
              <Label x:Name="lblPlatform"
              Text="{Binding Platform}"
                     Font="Bold,Medium" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Release Date -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label Text="Release Date:"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
              <Label x:Name="lblReleaseDate"
              Text="{Binding ReleaseDate}"
                     Font="Bold,Medium" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Summary -->
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
              <Label x:Name="lblSummary"
              Text="{Binding Summary}"
                     Font="Bold,Medium" />
            </StackLayout>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

And here's my .cs:

```
namespace Finale
{
  public partial class DetailsPage : ContentPage
  {
        public ObservableCollection<Details> Details { get; set; }

        DatabaseManager objDB;
        List<ToDo> DID;
        int prevGameID;

        public DetailsPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
            GetDetails ();
            this.BindingContext = new Details();
    }

        public async Task GetDetails()
        {
            objDB = new DatabaseManager ();
            DID = objDB.ViewNextG ();
            prevGameID = DID [0].gameid;
            try {
                Details = new ObservableCollection<Details>();

                var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("tblGameDetails")
                    .WhereEqualTo("gameid", prevGameID);
                IEnumerable<ParseObject> games = await query.FindAsync ();

                foreach (ParseObject game in games) {
                    int detailsid = game.Get<int>("id");
                    string gametitle = game.Get<String>("gametitle");
                    string developer = game.Get<String>("developer");
                    string publisher = game.Get<String>("publisher");
                    string platform = game.Get<String>("platform");
                    DateTime releasedate = game.Get<DateTime>("releasedate");
                    string image = game.Get<String>("image");
                    string summary = game.Get<String>("summary");

                    Details.Add(new Finale.Details
                        {
                            ID = detailsid,
                            Name = gametitle,
                            Developer = developer,
                            Publisher = publisher,
                            Platform = platform,
                            ReleaseDate = Convert.ToString(releasedate),
                            Image = image,
                            Summary = summary,
                        });

                    Console.WriteLine(detailsid + " " + gametitle);

                }
                lblTitle.BindingContext = Details[0].Name;
                imgCover.BindingContext = Details[0].Image;
                lblDeveloper.BindingContext = Details[0].Developer;
                lblPublisher.BindingContext = Details[0].Publisher;
                lblPlatform.BindingContext = Details[0].Platform;
                lblReleaseDate.BindingContext = Convert.ToString(Details[0].ReleaseDate);
                lblSummary.BindingContext = Details[0].Summary;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error: ", e.Message);
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should store the DetailsItem in a property

```
public Details TheDetailsItem { get; set; }
```

2 - Then bind to that object

```
public DetailsPage()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      TheDetailsItem = new Details ();
      this.BindingContext = TheDetailsItem;
      GetDetails ();
}
```

Avoid setting bindingcontext for each field.So

3 - Remove:

```
lblTitle.BindingContext = Details[0].Name;
imgCover.BindingContext = Details[0].Image;
lblDeveloper.BindingContext = Details[0].Developer;
lblPublisher.BindingContext = Details[0].Publisher;
lblPlatform.BindingContext = Details[0].Platform;
lblReleaseDate.BindingContext = Convert.ToString(Details[0].ReleaseDate);
lblSummary.BindingContext = Details[0].Summary;
```

4 - and replace with

```
TheDetailsItem.Name = Details[0].Name;
TheDetailsItem.Developer = Details[0].Developer;
etc...
```

5 - Your Details Object should implements INotifyPropertyChanged (see DemoCustomer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx))